# Are there any frameworks to link payments between customers and sellers?

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments, android-pay, applepay

I am working on an app that enables customers to make on-the-go payments. I want the payment experience to be as effortless and hands-free as possible. 
An example use case would be to fill up the gas on a gas station and not have to take out your wallet at all. 
Ideally, I'd like to use services like Google Wallet, Paypal or Apple Pay etc. But I am not sure how to process and post the payment to the actual seller. In this case, what I can't figure out is how would I determine the actual seller and how I can link the seller account to my app, so the payment goes to the actual seller.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: You are attacking a pretty big problem there, right in the center of what the major services you mentioned are trying to do. I did not see any contact info on your profile, but if you want to connect outside stack overflow I could give you some background (I've worked in this space extensively).

Comment: Thanks for offering to help. I'd love to get a few pointers and educate myself more. I didn't see any contact info on your profile either. I am not sure why my email might not be visible on my profile. But swap1712 at g mail is my email. Please feel free to say hi and I will be happy to explain what is it exactly that I potentially want to do